# JS animate scaling of background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to repeat this effect:
http://www.google.com/culturalinstitute/#!home (view in chrome, image starts to scale after 2-3 seconds )

i try to do this with jquery animate and background-size property:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bg').animate({'background-size':'105%'}, 5000)
})
```

But image is flinches in every popular browser

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an inline image instead of a background image it should be much smoother. Use z-index to get around content overlapping issues.

So you will be animating an img instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bg').animate({'width':'105%'}, 5000);
})
```

Here's an example -> http://jsfiddle.net/frUvf/